# How to deploy a qt based app(developed on Mac) to Windows?

Tags: c++, macos, qt

I developed a desktop Qt app on macOs. I want to execute my app on windows. I've looked that pages:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/osx-deployment.html
https://godhc.wordpress.com/2012/06/10/build-your-qt-project-on-windows-and-mac-osx/
But it did not make sense well. 
Can someone explain me how to do that?

Comment: Different operating systems, different executable files. You can't copy a compiled program targeted at one system to a complete different system. Either set up a cross-compilation environment, or get Windows and use it to build (you probably need to do that anyway, since even a program using a portable library like Qt often needs tweaks for each target platform).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to recompile it on windows. you have to make sure your code doesn't use macos "framworks" or unix or linux specific functions.

i recommend downloading a precompiled static QT as building it is impossible. you can get that [here](https://www.npcglib.org/~stathis/blog/precompiled-qt4-qt5/) and using the visual studio compiler, you will have to download visual studio and all the c++ addons and stuff.

!! edit what ever directory your cmd is in is the output of the qmake !!
 you then open up cmd and run the static compiled QT's qmake on the .pro file of your project. e.g.

```
E:\QT_projects\QT\qt5-5.7.1-vs2015\qt5-x86-static-release\bin\qmake.exe E:\QT_projects\variable-length-string-editor-for-binaries\StringEditer.pro
```

that will make the makefile. and then open the visual studio cmd called "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2017" for me opening the start menu and typing it in will show it.

you then navigate to the folder where the make files that qmake generated e.g.

```
cd E:\QT_projects\variable-length-string-editor-for-binaries
```

then run nmake on release or debug or just nmake e.g.

```
nmake release
```